# Cannot pass unicode dynamically DroidText, ANdroid

Tags: android, unicode

I'm trying to create a pdf with chinese text, So initially im converting chinese to unicode then add write it to pdf. But i can only write static variables to pdf. My english is bit poor so please check the code and output i obtain from the pdf created.

```
 Document document = new Document();
 PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(filepath));
 document.open();

 Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

             String   name= "\\u" + Integer.toHexString('取'| 0x10000).substring(1) ;
             String temp="\u53d6";
          //  Log.d( name , temp);
             InputStream inputStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.koz);
             byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
             inputStream.read(buffer);
             BaseFont bfComic = BaseFont.createFont("koz.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true, false, buffer, null);
             Font font = new Font(bfComic, 12);
             p.setFont(FontChinese);
             p.add(temp);
             document.add(p); // adding unicode staticaly
             p.add(name);
             document.add(p); // adding dynamically
             document.close();
```

OUTPUT : 
 取 
\u53d6